# Reference parameters are not allowed with RFC

Tags: abap, saprfc, function-module

Can anyone advise me on this error?

[image]

Comment: References are allowed only within the same stack/heap. You are trying to create a remote enabled Function Module and of course in this case only passing by value is allowed. If you actually do not want to enable remote capabilities, go to the attributes tab and select that this should be an ordinary function module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow @Jagger's advice and make your module not RFC or make all your parameters pass by value (without reference), it's the column with the heading 'Pa...'.

In RFC modules only TYPE and LIKE typing is allowed, references are prohibited.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the option (checkbox) I have highlighted in the image below must be enabled (i.e. checked):

[image]

Comment: What is "this option"? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it